# How to get data hide by js with java

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html

I crawler data form website exactly i want get  with java, I use jsoup library. However , i can't get any data from iframe , it empty

Here is code java :

```
  Document doc_film2 = Jsoup.connect("https://anime47.com/xem-phim-tuyet-ung-linh-chu-ep-01/158279.html")
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36")
               .get();
       Elements get_data1 = doc_film2.select("#player > iframe")
```

Here is html :

```html
<div class="block media" id="page-watch">

<div id="abd_mv">
<div id="player-area" style="width:100%;height:100%;"><div id="media" style="width:100%;height:100%;"><script type="text/javascript" src="https://anime47.com/player/jwplayer/jwplayer.js?v3"></script><script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="dWwDdbLI0ul1clbtlw+4/UHPxlYmLoE9Ii9QEw==";</script><div id="player" class="jwplayer jw-reset jw-state-paused jw-skin-beelden jw-stretch-uniform jw-breakpoint-4 jw-flag-user-inactive" tabindex="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"><iframe src="https://www.fembed.com/v/p6vg34pwx9j" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe></div><script type="text/javascript">var vasturl = BB.getVASTUrl(2000372);var playerInstance = jwplayer('player');playerInstance.setup({width: "100%",height: "100%",sources: [{file:"https://anime47.com/player/mp4.mp4",label:"api","type":"mp4"}],autostart: 'true',image: "https://anime47.com/tool/googlevid/play.jpg","skin" : {"url":"https://anime47.com/player/jwplayer/skins/beelden.css","name": "beelden",},"advertising": {client: "googima",tag: vasturl},});</script><style type="text/css">body{background: #000}.jwplayer.jw-flag-aspect-mode, .video-js {width:100% !important; height: 100% !important}#player{text-align: center;color:#fff;}</style> <script>playerInstance.on('firstFrame', function() {
 document.getElementById('player').innerHTML = '<iframe src=https://www.fembed.com/v/p6vg34pwx9j scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>';
});
</script></div></div>
</div>

</div>
```

Here is source web when i open

```html
<div class="movie-info"><div class="block-movie-info movie-info-box">

<div class="block media" id="page-watch">

<div id="abd_mv">
<div id="player-area" style="width:100%;height:100%;"><div id="media" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
</div></div>
</div>

</div>
```

Please help me !

Comment: JSOUP will not load any embedded resources ("http://...") on it's own.
The iframe is populated as resource.

Comment: SirFartALot  
So how should I do it?

Comment: Is there a library that supports it? If I see the website running a few js then the new iframe tag will appear. Is there a way to run js from java

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a Library called **HtmlUnit** which is js supported. Check it out on github.

Comment: Jsoup only grabs htm's data but does it take js of the website, does htmlUnit look like Jsoup? Or stronger? Faster ?

Comment: Jsoup gets only static html pages not js or css files. You can get help from Htmlunit which is js supported

Comment: thank bro I use Selenium and HeadLess Browser and find it